# How after building the dist folder in Webpack, move the bundle.js and css file into the statics folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

When I run my `npm run build` or `npm run build-dev`

[image]

It creates the index.html and manage2.bundle.js and manage2.css files in the root. I need to move those files into the static directory.

So the generated index.html below will actually work, with the correct paths:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Manage2</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="The TickerTags backend manage app">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300|Source+Sans+Pro:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="static/favicon.ico">
<link href="/static/manage2.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
    <div id="manage2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/manage2.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

### How is this acomplished? webpack.config below

```
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const src = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const stream = fs.createWriteStream("src/services/environment.js");
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
  stream.write('const env = "'+environment+'"\n');
  stream.write('export default env');
  stream.end();
});

module.exports = {
  context: src,
  entry: [
    "./index.js"
  ],
  output: {
    path: dist,
    filename: "manage2.bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/static/',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
          loader: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          publicPath: dist
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    quiet: true,
    publicPath: "",
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    stats: "errors-only",
    open: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "index.html"
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "manage2.css",
      disable: false,
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "static", to: "static" }])
  ]
};
// new webpack.DefinePlugin({ env: JSON.stringify(environment) })
```

#### My npm scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server -p",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
    "build-dev": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -d",
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This config is saving the *.js and *.css to the static folder.

```js
 output: {
 // the output bundle
 filename: '[name].[hash].js',
 // saves the files into the dist/static folder
 path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/static'),
 // set static as src="static/main.js as relative path
 publicPath: 'static/'
 },
```

With the HtmlWebpackPlugin you can generate a html file from a template. With this config in the Webpack plugins section the index.html is saved to the dist. folder with the correct path to the *.js and *.css.

```
plugins: [
   // is only working with npm run build
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: '',
    // save index.html one director back from the output path
    filename: '../index.html',
    template: 'index.template.ejs',
    hash: false
   }),
  ],
```

index.template.ejs

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>
  </title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Results in

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title> 
  </title>          
  <link href="static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>    
  <body>    
   <script type="text/javascript" src="static/main.js"></script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `output.path` is incorrect. It should be `path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'static')`.

And since now your `output.path` points to `dist/static`, set `publicPath` back to `/`.

Comment: When I did that, my localhost:8080 no longer works when I `npm run dev`. `Cannot GET /` also inside of my dist folder when I run `npm run build` I have static inside of static

Comment: Why is the devServer `publicPath: ""`? The documentation says it should always start and end with a forward slash.https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-publicpath-

Comment: Also, you may need to modify the devserver contentBase to include the static folder. I believe the dist folder is considered the working directory so it shouldn't need to be included. `contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "static")`