# Nodemon in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I am unable to run nodemon in a docker container. Here's the error I am getting: `[nodemon] Internal watch failed: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/usr/src/app/dist'`

Here is my image file:

```
## Use specific version of node
FROM node:10.16

## Get anything we may need for our container and run updates
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

## CREATE DIRECTORY
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

## Install packages
RUN yarn install

# BUNDLE APP SOURCE
COPY . .

# EXPOSE TARGET PORT
EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["yarn", "start:dev"]
```

Here is the compose:

```
    build: ./server/
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports: 
      - "3001:3001"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and here is start:dev:

`cross-env NODE_ENV=development tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess \"nodemon dist/main.js\"`

I have tried to increase the file watchers limit like so `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`, but I haven't figured out a way to do it (appears impossible to do so in compose/Dockerfile).

`docker container stats` is fine:

```
R ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS

4050a37b3352        server     8.87%               324.6MiB / 15.57GiB   2.04%               79.1kB / 6.87kB     48MB / 1.26MB       50
```

Here is `ps aux` inside the docker container:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.3 760916 57112 ?        Ssl  03:24   0:00 node /opt/yarn-v1.17.3/bin/yarn.js start:dev
root        29  0.0  0.0   4280   488 ?        S    03:24   0:00 /bin/sh -c cross-env NODE_ENV=development tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess "nodemon dist/main.js"
root        30  0.0  0.1 561684 21880 ?        Sl   03:24   0:00 /usr/local/bin/node /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=development tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess nodemon dist/
root        37  0.0  0.1 561768 23564 ?        Sl   03:24   0:00 /usr/local/bin/node /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess nodemon dist/main.js
root        46 12.9  1.2 781216 196912 ?       Sl   03:24   2:09 /usr/local/bin/node /usr/src/app/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -p tsconfig.build.json --watch
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    03:24   0:00 [sh] <defunct>
root        71  0.3  0.5 765520 96992 ?        Sl   03:24   0:03 /usr/local/bin/node dist/main dist/main.js
root        82  0.0  0.0  18180  2924 pts/0    Ss+  03:25   0:00 bash
root        92  6.0  0.0  18180  3064 pts/1    Ss   03:40   0:00 bash
root        99  0.0  0.0  36632  2828 pts/1    R+   03:40   0:00 ps aux
```

Comment: you do not need to watch `'/usr/src/app/dist` its static file and server does not need to restart on such changes

Comment: @Adiii dist is not a static file, it is being watched by tsc-watch and recompiled after changes

Comment: if i am not wrong , we got `dist` after ng build and we do not work on dist but its generated?

Comment: @Adiii I'm not sure I understand. I'm not running ng build anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439930/how-after-building-the-dist-folder-in-webpack-move-the-bundle-js-and-css-file-i

Comment: @Adiii that is not relevant... there is no static directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198980/discussion-between-adiii-and-chasen-bettinger).

Comment: you might find a solution to this but you will soon realize that docker slows development a lot. Docker is great to ship your applications and run them consistently  in different contexts. But when it comes to development, I recommend you do it on the host and forget about Docker. Your issue is with docker machine (the underlying virtual machine where docker is actually running). And if I am right you need to change the settings there, you cannot do it only with a Dockerfile.

Comment: @Mihai I think that is what I'm discovering. I'm using this as an opportunity to learn and I think I've figured out that docker for development just isn't that great.

Answer (score 1):

As Mentioned by @Mihae this will slow your development, but for your learning purpose, you need to modify your dockerfile, as such operation required `privileged` mode and is only available when your container bootup, you can modify them at build time.

```
## Use specific version of node
FROM node:10.16
## Get anything we may need for our container and run updates
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
## Install packages
RUN yarn install


#creating entrypoint script with some debug log you can remove after debuging
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh \n\
echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches before update" \n\
cat /etc/sysctl.conf\n\
echo "______________________updating inotify __________________________" \n\
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sysctl -p \n\
echo "updated value is" \n\
cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep fs.inotify \n\
exec yarn start:dev \
" >> /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
# EXPOSE TARGET PORT
EXPOSE 3001
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Build:

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

Now, do not forget to pass `--privileged` this is required for `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` to change its value.

```
docker run --privileged -ti myimage
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this out in a bit! :)

Comment: pleasure, let me know if there is any issue :)